# Auth::check() return false in custom middleware, what's wrong?

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

Auth::check() return false in custom middleware, What's wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The middleware is ran before the session one. Also, make sure to post code in your question instead of screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... please do not put pictures of code, code is text; you can copy and paste text into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the default authentication setup that would be using sessions. You defined the middleware that you created to be a global middleware. These run before the route middleware. The `web` group of middleware provides the session support for authentication to work. This is a group of route middleware and is running after your global middleware so you don't have access to the session, hence authentication yet.

Since this middleware is only there to check something based on authentication that requires the session, this should be appended to your `web` group of middleware in `$middlewareGroups` instead so it will run in the appropriate order.